Raydium Trading Api slippage settings
Hello guys i can't find it anywhere but i would like to set slippage to automatic, instead of using fixed numbers, is it possible?I cant figure out where to look for this kind of information, i obviously tried to read Raydium api docs but they only mention numbers. Thank you for you answers
